# Cast method to function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Maybe im just stupit, but I experiments a bit with WebRTC and the ondatachannel callback takes a function. Is it possible, to do this with a method of a Typescript class instead?. I hope you could help me.

```
export class MainComponent implements onViewInit {
    peerConnection = null;

    onViewInit() {
         this.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
          this.peerConnection.ondatachannel = this.receiveChannelCallbackt;
    }
    onMessage(event):void {
      console.log("test);
    }
    receiveChannelCallbackt(event)  {
     event.channel.onmessage= onMessage;
}
```

Comment: You will probably want to use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) or have a new function which calls the method on an object.  But without a [mcve] as described by [ask] it's hard to give you a more specific answer.  Good luck!

Comment: ok, so i added a code example. Is it possible to replace the function through a method call?

Comment: Sorry, but that example isn't complete: the types `OnInit` and `AfterViewInit` are not defined.  Ideally an [mcve] should be self-contained so you can drop it into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and the only issue present is the one you are concerned with.  I'm still not sure what your question is, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, I dont ask many questions on StackOverflow. Now I edited the Code so that is more reproducible

Comment: Please [edit this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FkUEsB2AwhALaT7D7y5lLAmUyYT4BquwA7gJL67wBvAFBxRcMMGBRi+Cghi4WcALxx8AVyRIA3EJFiW7Lr34AKAJRxhYm3BgALXGgB0EqTLkKlqipzgAlABVCAAVJaRZPRXwLXVsxBydXcI9geWjnFgATFBgUBHsUWWAkFTtHFyg04FwAN2BCQuKkQhQtACN8gGsYOLEAX31RFixgDBQAc2BTYHqqcwAuOFqIXCyrIdsEFjQIOmckCAnTACIYMZhzPtFBmyqEGvrGoooWtqROhB6ZucuN+NEs0YzgKLxKmXwDHGUzKIzGaEmwGucH6cCAA) until the only issue present is the one you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) as @jcalz suggested in the first comment.

```js
this.peerConnection.ondatachannel = this.receiveChannelCallbackt.bind(this);
```

Now when the `peerConnection.ondatachannel` will be called, your class method will be invoked with correct [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).